# 12Vdc to 45VAC inverter

Tags: inverter

I would like to make an inverter from 12Vdc to 45Vac.

I am trying to simulate it into LTSpice but I can't get a Frequency of 60 Hz.

**Here is the Schematic:**

[image]

**BOM:**

Q1 & Q2 : 2N5877

R1 & R2 : 220ohm 2 W

Source : 12V+

TFO: ?

**The question:** 
How can I figure what kind of transformer I need ?

**Presently here is the output:**
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you think that should oscillate at 60 Hz? Where did you get the circuit from?

Comment: I found it there : https://www.electroschematics.com/7032/12v-to-120v-voltage-inverter/

Supposly the iron from the transformer would change the frequency.. but how can I simulate it into LTSpice ?

Comment: I am trying to make it oscillate to 60Hz.. But I don't know which parameter will affect only the frequency and not the Ampllitude.

Comment: You can simply **forget** about trying to make this simple circuit oscillate at 50 or 60 Hz. Sure you could tweak the component values so that **in the simulator** it works at 50 Hz but that will result in **unrealistic** components, for example, a transformer with the size of a washing machine. This circuit is simple and works at around 50 to 100 kHz. It simply **cannot do** what you expect from it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie could you explain me why it will be huge as you say ? On the website where I found the circuit it says : 
"The output frequency depends on the transformer iron and input voltage but not on the load. **The frequency range between 50 to 60 Hz with a 60-Hz transformer and car battery or equivalent source.** The output voltage depends on turns ratio and the difference between input voltage and transistor saturation voltage. For higher power, use larger transformers and transistors". Is this information completly wrong ? If so, what is wrong with it ?

Comment: The article schematic shows an unmarked component between the battery and the transformer, with no explanation in the article.  Might be a fusible link?

Comment: @stark yes I think it's a fuse.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the dark ages, I have built this kind of oscillator with 2N3055 power transistors. It is used with a 50/60Hz steel or silicon steel core transformer.

You are going to have to use a nonlinear core model to get it to behave sensibly, because this type of oscillator depends on core saturation, but more likely it will oscillate a bit higher or lower than normal mains frequency, which typically isn't a problem.

If you want to know the theory, this was invented in 1954 by the eponymous [George Royer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royer_oscillator) and you can find the original patent US2783384A [here](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/33/30/c3/37a4e97853a657/US2783384.pdf)